# "Stuttered" Movement when keypressed

Tags: c++, sfml

Learning SFML and making a game in C++ for the first time. My problem comes with movement of the character. I'm making an Astroids-like clone, and the movement, when the keys are pressed, aren't very smooth. The character stutters around, and stops when rotating and moving forward are pressed at the same time. Any help?

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Bullet.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

#define SPEED 10
#define ROTATION 15


Player::Player()
{
    this->_x = 150;
    this->_y = 150;
    this->_xspeed = 0;
    this->_yspeed = 0;
    this->_rotation = ROTATION;
    this->_user = this->loadSprite("/Users/ganderzz/Desktop/Programming/C_Plus/stest/stest/Resources/Player.png");
    this->_user.setOrigin(16, 16);
}

void Player::Collision(RenderWindow & in)
{
    if(this->_x >= (in.getSize().x-32) || this->_x <= 0)
        this->_xspeed = 0;
}

void Player::Move(Event & e)
{
        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
        {
            this->_user.rotate(this->_rotation);
        }
        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
        {
            this->_user.rotate(-this->_rotation);
        }
        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W))
        {
            this->_yspeed = -sinf((90 + this->_user.getRotation()) * 3.14 / 180) * SPEED;
            this->_xspeed = -cosf((90 + this->_user.getRotation()) * 3.14 / 180) * SPEED;

            this->_x += this->_xspeed;
            this->_y += this->_yspeed;
        }
        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Space))
        {
            Bullet b(this->_x,this->_y,this->_user.getRotation());
        }
}

void Player::Draw(RenderWindow & in)
{
    this->_user.setPosition(this->_x, this->_y);
    in.draw(this->_user);
}

Sprite Player::loadSprite(std::string filename)
{
    this->_texture.loadFromFile(filename, IntRect(0,0,32,32));

    return Sprite(this->_texture);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is due to time management, if it is a small 2D you probably have a high FPS rate.

And then your `move` event is call way to many times and create this stutter.

You should limit you framerate, and try to add a clock to your event if limiting framerate is not enough.

You can find what you need in [this page of the doc](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/window-time.php)

If it is not that at all, show us your main loop, maybe you have something taking a lot of ressources there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Turns out I had things arranged wrong in the main, and need to add the clock. Thanks for the help!